# How to convert NSdata to float

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, audio

I've got a C++ method for audio processing which accept float 2d array. I have written a wrapper method using objective c for that method.

Now I need to convert audio file from objective c and send that audio data for that method.

Ive converted one of the audio file to `NSdata` using the below code

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"adaharem" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

How can I convert this NSdata to float 2d array  in objective c ?

Comment: An MP3 file is not just a sequence of floating point audio samples, you cannot just convert the file contents to a float array you need to decode the MP3 data.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537505/ios-how-to-read-an-audio-file-into-a-float-buffer