# How to load an Audio File in Swift 2 and store it as an array of floats (IOS)

Tags: ios, audio, swift2, avaudioplayer, core-audio

I'm new to Swift and IOS programming. I want to load an audio file in Swift 2, to do some signal processing. But I'm not able to load an audio file and store it as an array of floats. Can anybody give me a hint on literature or even a working code example on how to load an audio file? I searched the forums, but none of the old topics seems to do the trick.

Here's my Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


var audio: AVAudioPlayer!
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("nameOfFile", ofType:"wav")!
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

do {
    let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    audio = sound
} catch {
    // couldn't load file
}
```

error message: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Thank you in advance (and sorry for the possibly dumb question)

Comment: Your question is rather vague.  Have you ever written any code for opening and reading audio files using CoreAudio API or AVAudioPlayer API? Being new to Swift doesn't mean being new to iOS programming. Being new to iOS programming doesn't mean being unfamiliar with audio file formats and digital audio or DSP. There is a [CA textbook](http://www.informit.com/store/learning-core-audio-a-hands-on-guide-to-audio-programming-9780321636843) in C and Obj-C and its tutorial code ported to [Swift 2.0](https://github.com/AlesTsurko/LearningCoreAudioWithSwift2.0)

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537505/ios-how-to-read-an-audio-file-into-a-float-buffer?rq=1) may also be useful. If you want to read the entire file into an _array of desired format_, you have to take care of declaring it and allocating it programmatically. I'm not familiar with how fast _Swift_ is in low-level DSP. These critical routines are traditionally written in plain-C.

Comment: @user3078414: Thanks for the textbook. I'm fairly familiar with DSP and audio. But I only worked with Matlab. And from a Matlab Developer's perspective some concepts of IOS and Swift seem very confusing - for example all the lines of code you need to load an audio file in. ;)

The post you sent me, looks very promising, thank you for that aswell. I edited my question and posted my code and the error.

Comment: Matlab is great for showing how things work. For 'real-life' audio and DSP it is critical that the code is robust, _fast_ and poses no real-time constraints (allocating objects, blocking, waiting, etc.). The following site may also give some valuable information. Make sure to read it [carefully](http://atastypixel.com/blog/objective-c-or-swift/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will read up on that. For my purpose, I don't need fast routines. I'm doing offline processing in vDSP, so some extra processing time doesn't matter. I just need to get that audio file loaded. :)

Comment: Make sure to allocate and initialize all the vDSP vectors **outside** the processing callback.